# Android webview on Android 2.1, get error after load

Tags: android, webview, get, load

I load WebView and get the source code and put into alert dialog. After alert dialog is closed, I receive this thread:

```
Uncaught handler: thread WebViewCoreThread exiting due to uncaught exception
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2683)
at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:557)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:255)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:255)
at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:4324)
at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:2988)
at card.eximbank.CardExim.function(CardExim.java:413)
at card.eximbank.CardExim$MyJavaScriptInterface.getHTML(CardExim.java:74)
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.loadUrl(BrowserFrame.java:149)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore.loadUrl(WebViewCore.java:1449)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$1400(WebViewCore.java:48)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:890)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:611)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

this is my WebView:

```
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
browser.getCertificate();
browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");

final Activity MyActivity = this;
browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

 public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
 setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
 MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); // Make the bar
 if (progress == 100) {
  setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
 }
}
@TargetApi(8)
public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cmsg)
{
 resultCont = cmsg.message();
 function();
 return true;
}
});

browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String    failingUrl)
{ }

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
 return true;
}

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
{   
 if(countOnLoad == 2){
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7) {    
   view.loadUrl("javascript:console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0].innerHTML);");    
  }else{
   view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.getHTML(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML);");
  }
   countOnLoad = 1;
  }else{
   countOnLoad++;
   }
 } 

 @TargetApi(8)
 public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {

  handler.proceed();
 }
 });
```

button from main activity:

```
signIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View arg0) {
 browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test_exim.html?username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
 }
});
```

When I click on the button, I load a local file on WebView. This file submit form and load other URL into WebView. I want to get source code from WebView and put in TextView. But, WebView do not visible.

Comment: Code snippets and what you aim to do, please.

Comment: `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views` what are you doing when you close the dialog? Show the code, like Jan1337z already said.

Comment: When I close the dialog, I do nothing.